# Is there a command in Visual Studio to get the projects dependent on a project within a solution?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Let us say I have 20 projects in a solution, and one of them is named `Foo`.

I would like to get a list of projects *that have `Foo` as their reference.*

Until now, I have been using a small C# program I have written for that which loads every assembly in the solution and reads from its manifest (`Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies`).

However, it is tedious. I am wondering if there's a Visual Studio command to display this list.

I am using **Visual Studio Professional 2013** but I'd be happy to know if any version of Visual Studio has that command, and I'll switch to using that one.

**A note for the casual reader**

I am *not* looking for a way to find a project's dependencies, i.e. a list of projects on which the current project is dependent. For that, there's the **Build Dependencies** context-menu command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it, the [Dependency Graph](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409453(v=vs.120).aspx) feature might suit your needs. You need VS Ultimate Edition, though (any version from 2010 to 2015).

I'm not aware of any other feature that comes close to doing what you're asking.